# Can I Setup a Windows Server 2012 Foundation as an additional DC to an AD domain

Tags: windows-server-2012

We are a small 8 user office already have Windows Server 2012 R2 as a DC.  Just bought a 2nd server with Windows Server 2012 Foundation and realized it can not be set up as member server to the existing AD domain.  Instead, can I set it up as an additional Domain Controller or backup DC in the AD domain?  We intend to use this as a file server for an ERP software.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679892.aspx

"In the Windows Server 2012 Foundation operating system, the server must be a member of a workgroup or, if joined to a domain, joined at the root of the forest as a domain controller."

So if your existing domain consists of only one domain with no trusts to other domains, this documentation indicates that you can join it to such a domain.